# Detect token at one place but ignore at other place in antlr4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

One of the rules in my antrl4 parser is as follows. A vertex is represented as list of coorindates,each coordinate separated by a space.

```
vertex  returns[Vertex value]
    :{$value = new Vertex();} e1=coordinate{$value.addCoordinate($e1.value);}+ 
                             (SPACEDELIMIT e2=coordinate{$value.addCoordinate($e2.value);})* LINEBREAK
    ;

LINEBREAK: NEWLINE+;
SPACEDELIMIT: ' ';
fragment NEWLINE:('\n'|'\r');    
fragment WHITESPACE: (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\u000C')+ { skip(); } ;
```

I want to detect those spaces in between as delimiters, and also the linebreaks, but would like to ignore or skip spaces or '\n' or '\t' characters at other places. How do I achieve it. I am really beginner at antlr4 and I am not sure why I am using fragment keyword in the kexer. It was just a desperate attempt to make things work.

Comment: Why do you need a space there? Just skip all spaces.

Comment: Could you post a sample input and your complete grammar so far?

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks. I did that and seems to work. But what about Newlines.

Comment: Well, that depends on your language. Skip them if you can, and if they're significant, *and* you want them to be able to exist between your coordinates, you'll need to add them in between these coordinates.